# Single Line Address for MapQuest

Tags: mapquest

I'm trying to provide other map options besides *just* Google. Unfortunately a single HTTP query (e.g. location=123+main+street) only seems to be readily supported by Google.

I had no luck trying to find anything about embedding in the documentation and decided to email them directly:

> The MapQuest business products
>   (https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/) support both single
>   line input "location=1555+Blake+St+Denver+CO+80202+US" and the
>   advanced, 5-box method
>   ("street=1555+Blake+St&city=Denver&state=CO&postalCode=80202&country=US").
>   Our API and SDK also lets you add the mapping/geocoding/routing
>   functions to your site without embedding links to the consumer site at
>   www.MapQuest.com.

Okay, so `location=123+main+street` *should* be supported in theory. However no example was provided. So using the `iframe` URL from the more client-oriented approach I tried the following without luck:

https://www.mapquest.com/embed/?location=1555+Blake+St+Denver+CO+80202+US

That just shows the map of the US as a whole.

How do I get the single HTTP query `location` to work for MapQuest embedding?

Correct: `location=1555+Blake+St+Denver+CO+80202+US` (single HTTP query).

Incorrect: `street=1555+Blake+St&city=Denver` (multiple HTTP queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On this page: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/tools/link-to-mapquest/
2. Scroll down to **Link to MapQuest Wizard**.
3. Click on **Map a Location**.
4. Click on **Single Line Location**.
5. Click on the **Run Sample with Embed View Specifier** button.
6. Copy the URL from the new tab.

An example of the working MapQuest single HTTP query embedded page:

https://www.mapquest.com/embed/search/results?query=1555%20Blake%20St%20Denver%20CO%2080202&centerOnResults=1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mix of MapQuest APIs and MapQuest.com. Check out the [Link to MapQuest](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/tools/link-to-mapquest/) documentation. I think the Map a Location > Fielded Location is what you're after.

Comment: I contacted support after *not* finding anything useful on their documentation page. So a link to their not helpful documentation page isn't going to help me here. :-|